# Replace a variable in a numerical evaluated integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I evaluated the following integral in a numerical way:

$V(R)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{0.5e^{-0.4k^2}\left(\frac{26000}{16k^2}-\frac{1800}{1+0.1k^2}-270\right)r\sin[k r]\sin[kR] dk dr}{R(1+8.3\times 10^{-6}e^{2r})}}$

I use these comands to evaluate the integral:

```
tb1 = Table[{R,   NIntegrate[fs[k, r], {k, 0, Infinity}, {r, 0, Infinity}, 
Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3]}, {R, 0.01, 20, 0.1}]
```

where $fs(k,r)$ is the argument of the integral. I obtained a table and a plot. Everything so far it's okay, but now, I have to make a change of variable to make other two integrals:

$V(R)\rightarrow V(\frac{\sqrt{r+r^{\prime}+2rr^{\prime}\cos[\theta]}}{2})$

but since what I got in the previous integration is a table of values, I don't know how to proceed!. The first integral is :

$v(r,r^{\prime})=\int_{-1}^{1}{V\left(\frac{\sqrt{r+r^{\prime}+2rr^{\prime}x}}{2}\right)e^{\left(\frac{2rr^{\prime}x}{3}\right)}dx}$

I have had replaced $Cos[\theta]$ with $x$. After that, I have to make a final integration:

$v(r)=\int_{0}^{10}{v(r,r^{\prime})}$

I will appreciate any help !! Thanks :D

Comment: `Interpolation[tb1][Sqrt[r + rp + 2 r rp Cos[t]]/2]`?

Comment: Sorry Michael, can you explain me , please ?

Comment: `Interpolation[tb1]` represents $V(R)$. Do you know what [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) is?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to use it in Mathematica. I put what you wrote and I get a mistake .

Comment: Your code is incomplete so the ability of people to help you will be limited.  You say you got an error, but do not say what error.  If I replace your integral with a completely defined expression such as `Sin[R]`, I get no error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3HgHV.png

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning mathematica and there are a lot stuff I don't know how to use. I defined the interpolation as tb1i and there is no error. However , I don't know how to use this new function in the integrals. Think I should get a table in both. I should take values for r and rp from 0 to 15, say.